# Как реализовать подстановку заголовочных файлов в зависимости от платформы

Tags: c++, header, c++17, препроцессор

Предположим, у меня есть папка **root**, в ней 3 папки **Windows**, **Linux** и **APPLE**.
В каждой из них хранится заголовочный файл **hpp** и файл с кодом **cpp**.
В **root** же хранится заголовочный файл **thirdparty.hpp**, который должен подставлять библиотеки в зависимости от платформы компиляции.
**Скрин**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каждом файле (**Win32.hpp, LINUX.hpp, APPLE.hpp**) содержится одинаковый набор разных функций (функции называются идентично, но работают по-разному, т.к. платформенозависимы)

Например:
**WIN32.hpp**:

```
#ifndef WIN3264TP_HPP
#define WIN3264TP_HPP

    #include <windows.h>

    unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory();


#endif
```

**WIN32.cpp**:

```
#include "../WIN32/WIN32.hpp"


unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory() {
    typedef BOOL(WINAPI* PGMSE)(LPMEMORYSTATUSEX);

    PGMSE pGMSE = (PGMSE)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "GlobalMemoryStatusEx");

    if (pGMSE){
        MEMORYSTATUSEX mi;
        memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX));
        mi.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
        if (pGMSE(&mi) == TRUE) return mi.ullAvailPhys;
        pGMSE = 0;
    }

    if (!pGMSE){
        MEMORYSTATUS mi;
        memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(MEMORYSTATUS));
        mi.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUS);
        GlobalMemoryStatus(&mi);
        return mi.dwAvailPhys;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**LINUX.hpp**:

```
#ifndef LINUX_HPP
#define LINUX_HPP

    #include <fstream>
    #include <limits>

    unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory();

#endif // LINUX_HPP
```

**LINUX**.cpp:

```
unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory() {

    std::string token;
    std::ifstream file("/proc/meminfo");

    while (file >> token) {
        if (token == "MemAvailable:") {
            unsigned long mem;
            if (file >> mem) return mem;
            else return 0;
        }
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**thirdparty.hpp** же должен указывать функции из какого файла должны компилироваться, а из какого игнорироваться.

**Например**:

```
#ifndef THIRDPARTY_HPP
#define THIRDPARTY_HPP

// WINDOWS FUNCTIONS
#ifdef __WIN32
#include "WIN32/WIN32.hpp"

// APPLE FUNCTIONS
#elif __APPLE__
#include "APPLE/APPLE.hpp"

// LINUX FUNCTIONS
#elif __linux__
#include "LINUX/LINUX.hpp"
#endif

namespace ThirdParty{

    unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory(){
        return GetAvailableMemory();
    }

}

#endif // THIRDPARTY_HPP
```

Вроде все составлено логично, но почему-то не компилируется...
**Ошибки**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете объяснить - что я делаю не так?
И как можно реализовать то, о чем я написал выше?

Comment: Скорее всего, вы компилируете все 3 `.cpp` файла, линкер пытается их слинковать и вы получаете ошибку множественного определения.

Comment: @eanmos и как тогда сделать так, чтобы линковались только нужные файлы?

Comment: На скриншоте вроде 6 листьевых директорий и все с одним файлом, а текстом сказано, что 3 и с 2 файлами

Comment: @dIm0n На скриншоте также видно 3 директории с 2мя файлами в каждой. Просто Qt Creator разделил показ на cpp (снизу) и hpp (сверху)

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG понял, в реальности они по-другому лежат, а IDE отображает так

Comment: @dIm0n ну, лежат они и по IDE в одном и том же месте (названия папок одинаковые), но да - отображает немного может быть непонятно

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, ну если вам нужен quick hack, можно просто обернуть весь `.cpp` файл в `#ifdef __linux__`. Правда, стандарт не разрешает пустые единицы трансляции, но в принципе, должно скомпилироваться. А так есть много разных решений.

Comment: Если фукцнии одни и те же для каждой платформы, то лучше помести их в один файл, и там уже используй директивы препроцессора для включения/отключения необходимых вариантов. Либо в CMake, можно запросто включать нужные файлы через команду `if ({UNIX|WIN32|APPLE})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь написать одну и ту же функцию для разных платформ, то просто поступите правильно. А точнее, берем один `.h` и один `.cpp`, при этом в заголовочном файле, допустим будет определение функции:

```
#ifndef GET_MEMORY_HPP
#define GET_MEMORY_HPP 1

// Здесь не нужно ничего подключать. Ну или хотя бы стандартную библиотеку <cstdint>
// #include <cstdint>

// ::uint64_t or ::size_t

unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory();

#endif
```

Далее, уже в файле `cpp`, используем макросы, и переопределение кода, который будет компилироваться, а значит:

```
#include "GetMemory.hpp"

#if defined WIN32 || defined _WIN32 || defined __WIN32__ || defined __NT__
#   if !defined PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#       define PLATFORM_WINDOWS 1
#       include <Windows.h>
#   endif
#elif __APPLE__
// к примеру apple не поддерживается.
#   error "Sorry but Apple platform not supported now..."
#elif __linux__
#   if !defined PLATFORM_LINUX
#       define PLATFORM_LINUX 1
#       include <fstream>
#       include <limits>
#   endif
#elif __unix__
#   if !defined PLATFORM_UNIX
#       define PLATFORM_UNIX 1
#   endif
#else
#   error "Unknown platform not supported..."
#endif /* PLATFORM_* */

unsigned long long GetAvailableMemory() {

    unsigned long long result = 0;

#if defined PLATFORM_LINUX

    std::string token;
    ::std::ifstream file("/proc/meminfo");

    while (file >> token) {
        if (token == "MemAvailable:") {
            unsigned long mem;
            if (file >> mem) {
                result = mem;
            }
        }
        file.ignore(::std::numeric_limits<::std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

#elif defined PLATFORM_WINDOWS

    typedef ::BOOL(WINAPI* PGMSE)(::LPMEMORYSTATUSEX);

    PGMSE pGMSE = (PGMSE)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "GlobalMemoryStatusEx");

    if (pGMSE){
        ::MEMORYSTATUSEX mi;
        (void) ::memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(::MEMORYSTATUSEX));
        mi.dwLength = sizeof(::MEMORYSTATUSEX);
        if (pGMSE(&mi) == TRUE) {
            result = mi.ullAvailPhys;
        }
        pGMSE = 0;
    }

    if (!pGMSE){
        ::MEMORYSTATUS mi;
        (void) ::memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(::MEMORYSTATUS));
        mi.dwLength = sizeof(::MEMORYSTATUS);
        ::GlobalMemoryStatus(&mi);
        result = mi.dwAvailPhys;
    }
#elif defined PLATFORM_MACOS
    ... и так далее
#else
#    pragma error "Function not supported by current platform"
#endif

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример выбора исходного кода для `qmake`

```
linux {
    SOURCES += libs/libsuper/impl/linux.cxx
}

win32 {
    SOURCES += libs/libsuper/impl/windows.cxx
}
```

Приведу более подробный пример с использованием `cmake`

Создаем только один заголовочный файл и несколько файлов реализации

```sh
$> ls ./
CMakeLists.txt  impl  libsuper.hxx
$> ls ./impl/
linux.cxx  windows.cxx
```

```cpp
// libsuper.hxx
#ifndef DEMO_LIBSUPER_HXX
#define DEMO_LIBSUPER_HXX

#include <cstdint>

namespace LibSuper {

    uint64_t getSuperValue();
}
#endif //DEMO_LIBSUPER_HXX
```

```cpp
// impl/linux.cxx
#include <libsuper.hxx>

namespace LibSuper
{
    uint64_t getSuperValue()
    {
        // linux specific
        return 0x42;
    }
}
```

```cpp
// impl/windows.cxx
#include <libsuper.hxx>

namespace LibSuper
{
    uint64_t getSuperValue()
    {
        // windows specific
        return 0x32;
    }
}
```

Создадим файл проекта для `cmake`

```
# libsuper/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(super_lib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# добавим общие исходники
set(lib_SRC)
list(APPEND lib_SRC libsuper.hxx)

message(STATUS "System is ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")

# определим ОС

if (WIN32)
    # Windows
    list(APPEND lib_SRC impl/windows.cxx)
elseif(UNIX)
    # Linux
    if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux")
        list(APPEND lib_SRC impl/linux.cxx)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} is not supported")
    endif()
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown system")
endif ()

# соберем нашу супер библиотеку
add_library(super ${lib_SRC})
target_include_directories(super PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Для проверки создадим проект клиента библиотеки

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <libsuper.hxx>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << LibSuper::getSuperValue() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(libsuper)

add_executable(demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE super)
```

Comment: `std::uint64_t`; проверять линупс с `strequal` [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9160335/13970074); собирать сорцы в переменную и потом делать таргет старая практика, лучше создавать таргет, где он логически должен быть, а сорцы добавлять позже во вложенном CMakeLists.txt, который находится как можно ближе к нужным сорцам

Comment: Первое - я использую qmake. Второе... уже описали выше

Comment: для qmake можно использовать подобный подход https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html